# Are decimals supported when specifying cache size values?

Tags: caching, patch-configuration

Are decimals not supported when configuring cache sizes? I recently noticed that setting a cache size to `1.6MB` resulted in the cache size being set to `16MB`:

### Patch Config

Below is the patch config where I set the cache size to `1.6MB`:
[image: patch config]

### `showconfig.aspx` Page

[image: site config]

### `cache.aspx` Page

[image: cache.aspx page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Commas `,` and periods `.` are stripped from the values. You can take a look at `Sitecore.StringUtil.ParseSizeString(string)` for proof, I've not found this officially documented anywhere.

Valid sizes examples:

- 12000 (bytes)
- 500KB (kilobytes)
- 25MB (megabytes)
- 2GB (gigabytes)

If you want 1.6MB, you're going to have to go with 1600KB.

More info: https://www.sitecorespark.com/blog/2018/8/why-sitecore-cache-sizes-are-listed-in-kb-mb-gb-in-configuration